# OpenGl texture yanks

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I use my class that inherited from QGraphicsItem. It has function in which I draw different stuff with help of OpenGL. Currently I want to load the texture and redraw it in every frame change. The texture loads fine and displays, but on starting of my application this texture ugly yanks. I can't figure out where is the problem, 'cause I'm a newbie in OpenGL. Here's my code that shows what I want to achive:

```
   void GLGraphicsItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * /* option */, QWidget *  widget)
{
    painter->beginNativePainting();

    static GLuint icoId;
    static int icoW;
    static int icoH;
    static bool first = true;

    if (first) {
        QImage t;
        QImage b;

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.1f);
        glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);

        b.load(":/res/example.png", "PNG");
        QImage fixedImage(b.width(), b.height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
        QPainter painter(&fixedImage);
        painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Source);
        painter.fillRect(fixedImage.rect(), Qt::transparent);
        painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOver);
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, b);
        painter.end();

        t = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(fixedImage);
        glGenTextures(1, &icoId);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, icoId);
        icoW = t.height();
        icoH = t.width();
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, t.width(), t.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.bits());
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    glViewport(100, 100, icoW, icoH);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, icoId);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    painter->endNativePainting();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me, please, for disturbing, but I found a reason. I just needed

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

before starting drawing. I hate myself for such a moments. I will not delete this question, 'cause I hope, this will help somebody.